# AS3 programming animation loop problems

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, animation

I'm tinkering with making an object move from left a certain distance to the right, then start over from the left over and over.

I'm curious to how it works. Currently I have this (simplified) code where 'rect' is supposed to be looped to the right:

```
  ok, this is the code non simplified: function preload(e:Event):void{
    var loadedBytes=loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
    var totalBytes=loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var rect=MovieClip(root).loader_rect;
    var startpos=rect.x=stage.x-rect.width;

       if(loadedBytes==totalBytes){
           removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, preloader);
           gotoAndStop(2); 
       }
       else{ 
           rect.x+=3.5+loadedBytes/totalBytes; 
         if(rect.x>=stage.x+stage.width) rect.x=startpos  

           else rect.x+=3.5+loadedBytes/totalBytes; 
       }
} (I get no errors, just  the animation isn't working)
```

To me it seems that should cover it. If rect's position is more than 200 move it to 0, otherwise move it right by 10px on each frame. But all it does is move rect by a few pixels to the right then stops. Why doesn't this work, is the logic incorrect?

Comment: _By a few pixels_. Do you mean 10? Can you show more code? Is it inside an `onEnterFrame` or anything?

Comment: yes, in pixels. The code is inside onEnterFrame. The thing is that it's being triggered when testing but dysfunctional - instead of moving 'rect' 200 pixels to the right it only moves by some 5 px then stops. So i'm wondering if the logic of this code is not right?

Comment: Well.. can you show more code.. it is kind of hard to help because the piece of code in your question should work.

Comment: ok, this is the code non simplified: function preload(e:Event):void{
 var loadedBytes=loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
 var totalBytes=loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
 var rect=MovieClip(root).loader_rect;
 var startpos=rect.x=stage.x-rect.width;

    if(loadedBytes==totalBytes){
     removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, preloader);
     gotoAndStop(2); 
    }
    else{ 
     rect.x+=3.5+loadedBytes/totalBytes; 
   if(rect.x>=stage.x+stage.width) rect.x=startpos  
    
     else rect.x+=3.5+loadedBytes/totalBytes; 
    }
} (I get no errors, just that the animation isn't working)

Comment: Put that in the question, not in a comment.

Comment: did that, but as walkietokyo mentioned it's the onEnterFrame that keeps resetting the movement to the right to the start position on each round, so now the problem is how to get around that.

Comment: did that, good for a start, but the animation still doesn't work, the bar just keeps moving to the right but never starts over again, as specified (or not specified, since it isn't working). I want the bar to keep starting over from the left once it moves out of view to the right.

Comment: If `stage.width` refers to the `flash.display.Stage`, you may want to use `stage.stageWidth` instead. The `stage.width` will change since the position of its children changed. Think of it as a rubberband that will stretch to fit all child elements. If you move one of the children outside of the original boundary, the boundary is recalculated. The `stageWidth` refers to the physical width of the stage and won't change due to its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code **resets** the x position of the `rect` object:

```
var startpos = rect.x = stage.x - rect.width;
```

This means that on every frame, the `rect` is moved to the above position, then moved *3.5 + a fraction between 0 and 1* pixels to the right. It will then be moved **an additional** *3.5 + a fraction between 0 and 1* pixels to the right.

So, on every frame the `rect` object will be moved to the x position of

```
stage.x - rect.width + 3.5 * 2 + [percent loaded] * 2
```

The `rect` will therefore never appear to move much (a maximum of 2 pixels over the course of the load).

Comment: Great catch. Is there anyway around it in an onEnterFrame event, given the code is sure to repeat? Can't think of anything now.

Comment: @user3274901 You could set the start position of the rectangle outside of the loader event handler. So, for example, before starting the loader, you set `rect.x = stage.x - rect.width;`. You *then* start the loader.

Comment: I did  move it outside now, but now while the rect moves to the right it doesn't return to startpos once reaching stage.x + stage.width. I'd like it to keep looping left-right, how can I get it to return to start position over and over?

Comment: @user3274901 As I commented on your post above: If `stage.width` refers to the `flash.display.Stage`, you may want to use `stage.stageWidth` instead. The `stage.width` will change since the position of its children changed. Think of it as a rubberband that will stretch to fit all child elements. If you move one of the children outside of the original boundary, the boundary is recalculated. The `stageWidth` refers to the physical width of the stage and won't change due to its child elements.

Comment: will try that, nicely explained, thanks. That worked, thanks a lot for all the help.